# Virtual mouse driver, possible X11 problems

Tags: kernel, xorg, x11, drivers, mouse

I created virtual mouse driver according to Essential Linux Device Drivers book. After I wrote coordinates `echo x y > /sys/ ... /coordinates` into sysfs node, my program generates event packets through event interface `/dev/input/event5` (I checked this). This event interface is attached to the GPM `gpm -m /dev/input/event5 -t evdev`. But mouse don't move.

**Maybe this will help: in Xorg.0.log i see the following:**

```
[ 666.521] (II) config/udev: Adding input device (/dev/input/event5)
[ 666.521] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
```

It seems, that code is ok, but some outer features interfere my module work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a huge amount of time, resolving this issue, and i would like to help other people, who run in this problem. I think some outer X11 features interfered my module work. After disabling GDM it now works fine (runlevel 3). Working code you can find here http://fred-zone.blogspot.ru/2010/01/mouse-linux-kernel-driver.html working distro ubuntu 11.04 (gdm disabled)